# Возможно ли инвертирование булевых свойств в Binding с помощью чистого XAML?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, binding

Есть CheckBox и ComboBox. ComboBox должен быть неактивным, если в CheckBox стоит галка, и активным - если не стоит.
Я знаю как сделать Binding в стандартном случае, когда всё наоборот - если IsChecked=true => то и IsEnabled=true.

```xml
    <CheckBox Name="CheckBox_Autoselect" IsChecked="True" />
    <ComboBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=CheckBox_Autoselect, Path=IsChecked}">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Type 1"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Type 2"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

А если нужно делать так: IsChecked=true => IsEnabled=false, возможно ли это реализовать аналогичным способом - только Binding, без кода C# ?

Comment: Это делается с помощью конвертора.

Comment: @ixSci, я видел способ с конвертером,  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"  и код C#. Если бы вопрос был только в том, как сделать, я бы и спрашивать не стал.

Comment: Другого способа нет. Можно ещё свой Binding написать, но это несколько сложнее :)

Comment: @ixSci, ок, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите по этой ссылке https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/98c224af-cac0-4108-88bb-1e97d701e3a8/checkbox-trigger-enabledisable-textbox?forum=wpf
или адаптированная версия под вас

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2">
  <ComboBox.Style>
    <Style>
      <Setter Property="ComboBox.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=checkBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ComboBox.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
  </ComboBox>
<CheckBox Name="checkBox" Grid.Row="3"/>
```

Comment: В варианте по ссылке ведь нет инверсии.  Жаль, что нет встроенной краткой версии в одну строку. Благодарствую за вариант решения.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте такой вариант: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CalcBinding/

Синтаксис:

```
<CheckBox Content="!IsChecked" IsChecked="{c:Binding !IsChecked}"/>
```

Примеры можно найти [тут](https://github.com/Alex141/CalcBinding/blob/master/README.md)